# Python EasyGUI multchoicebox - Quiz IF statement on multiple items not working

Tags: python, easygui

I would like to have an easyGUI multchoicebox display output based on the correct choices being made. The following doesn't work (i.e it doesn't show 'correct')

```
import easygui

fieldnames = ["Incorrect", "Correct", "Also Correct"]
choice = easygui.multchoicebox("Pick an option.", "", fieldnames)
if choice == fieldnames[1] and fieldnames[2]:
    easygui.msgbox('Correct!')
else:
    easygui.msgbox('Incorrect')

#Also tried:
#if choice == "Correct" and "Also Correct":
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "in" operator to check if the desired field was selected by the user.

Then, in order to apply the logic to both chosen values, simply add "and".

Here's the code, corrected and tested:

```
import easygui

fieldnames = ["Incorrect", "Correct", "Also Correct"]
choice = easygui.multchoicebox("Pick an option.", "", fieldnames)

if fieldnames[1] in choice and fieldnames[2] in choice:
    easygui.msgbox('Correct!')
else:
    easygui.msgbox('Incorrect')
```

Comment: Happy to help, @JohnCollins!

Answer (score 0):

```
if choice == fieldnames[1] and fieldnames[2]:
```

is the same as

```
if (choice == fieldnames[1]) and fieldnames[2]:
```

which means that it will check if `choice` equals `fieldnames[1]` and if `fieldnames[2]` is "truthy". (Which should be `True` if you select "Correct").

What you probably wanted to check is:

```
if choice in ( fieldnames[1], fieldnames[2] ):
```